# Connect Tableau to memsql

Tags: tableau-api, singlestore

Is there a way to connect Tableau to a memsql cluster ?

I hope there is a way as this [article](http://www.reuters.com/article/2015/06/15/idUSnMKWKxJSDa+1ee+MKW20150615) and this [page](http://www.memsql.com/releases/memcity/) suggest so .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can connect Tableau to MemSQL with Tableau's MySQL connector (MemSQL uses the same wire protocol as MySQL).